# Merge multiple multidimensional arrays and group by id column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, grouping

I have the following 3 multidimensional arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 191
            [categoria] => 7
            [prazo] => 8
            [desconto] => 45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 194
            [categoria] => 7
            [prazo] => 8
            [desconto] => 39
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 195
            [categoria] => 7
            [prazo] => 8
            [desconto] => 39
        )


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 191
            [categoria] => 7
            [pageviews] => 2103
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 194
            [categoria] => 7
            [pageviews] => 2445
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 195
            [categoria] => 7
            [pageviews] => 1560
        )

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 191
            [categoria] => 7
            [pedidos] => 3
            [valor] => 6501.583023
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 194
            [categoria] => 7
            [pedidos] => 1
            [valor] => 2217.968420
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 197
            [categoria] => 7
            [pedidos] => 2
            [valor] => 4405.517706
        )
```

And I would like to combine them keeping the keys 'id_produto' and 'categoria' and have something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 191
            [categoria] => 7
            [prazo] => 8
            [desconto] => 45
            [pageviews] => 2103
            [pedidos] => 3
            [valor] => 6501.583023
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 194
            [categoria] => 7
            [prazo] => 8
            [desconto] => 39
            [pageviews] => 2445
            [pedidos] => 1
            [valor] => 2217.968420
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_produto] => 195
            [categoria] => 7
            [prazo] => 8
            [desconto] => 39
            [pageviews] => 1560
            [pedidos] => 2
            [valor] => 4405.517706
        )
```

I tried `array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3)` and `array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2,$array3)` but it does copy them into an array with 9 elements. The following code worked for me but I'm looking for a faster solution, because I have thousands of ids:

```
foreach($array1 as $arr1=>$a){
    foreach($array2 as $arr2=>$b){
        if($a['id_produto'] == $b['id_produto']){
            $array1[$arr1]['pageviews'] = $b['pageviews'];
        }
    }
    foreach($array3 as $arr3=>$c){
        if($a['id_produto'] == $c['id_produto']){
            $array1[$arr1]['pedidos'] = $c['pedidos'];
            $array1[$arr1]['valor'] = $c['valor'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know for sure that all 3 arrays will be in the same order? Ditto Show the code you have tried even if it does not work!!

Comment: I edited my question. I basically tried to apply array_merge as I found in other questions but with no luck. Maybe there is another php function that can handle that. One thing I can try is to loop through them but its my last resort.

Comment: I can order them but its not guaranteed that all ids will be in all of the 3 arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why is your code slow? Assuming you have 1000 elements, your code is doing 1000*(1000+1000) = 2 millions iterations. That's why.

How to make it faster? Use **assoc arrays** instead of normal arrays, i.e. use `id_produto` as the key, so you can have direct access to the right elements instead of having to do a loop inside a loop.

To do that, first convert array2 and array3. Example with array2:

```
$new_array2 = array();
foreach ( $array2 as $row ) {
    $new_array2[$row['id_produto']] = $row;
}
$array2 = $new_array2;
```

Then merge:

```
foreach ( $array1 as & $row ) {
    $row['pageviews'] = $array2[$row['id_produto']['pageviews']];
    $row['pedidos'] = $array3[$row['id_produto']['pedidos']];
    $row['valor'] = $array3[$row['id_produto']['valor']];
}
```

Total : 3000 iterations only.

Comment: Heads up: you can replace the first `foreach` loop with just `array_column($array2, null, 'id_produto')` ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35451218))

Answer (score 2):

Key your arrays using `id_produto` and then simply use php's built in array functions, e.g.

```
array_replace_recursive($one, $two, $three)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the simplest solution without for-s or foreach-s and works with size of array

Comment: This + [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for re-keying = no need for `foreach` loops

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  It will not respect numeric keys properly.  This untested answer is damaging the Stack Overflow knowledge pool.

Comment: Proof: https://3v4l.org/ZbcF5  product 195 is damaged / merged with 197.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful:

```
$merged = array_merge($a, $b, $c);
$fixed_merge = Array();
for($i=0; $i < count($merged); $i++){
    echo $i;
    $this_id = $merged[$i]['id_produto'];
    if(isset($fixed_merge[$this_id])){
        $fixed_merge[$this_id] = array_merge($fixed_merge[$this_id], $merged[$i]);
    }else{
        $fixed_merge[$this_id] = $merged[$i];
    }
}
print_r($fixed_merge);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would populate the result array with the first array using `id_produto` for temporary keys.

In the loop, you can merge safely associative row data while grouping by these temporary keys.  After looping, re-index the result array with `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/K3Z77)) ([Demo version 2](https://3v4l.org/c9Mbv) -- likely slower)

```
$result = array_column($array1, null, 'id_produto');
foreach (array_merge($array2, $array3) as $row) {
    $result[$row['id_produto']] = array_merge($result[$row['id_produto']] ?? [], $row);
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

This approach will make more function calls than @rlanvin's answer (ergo it should be slightly slower in performance), but the advantage in not explicitly naming the specifically targeted columns from specific arrays is that this snippet will not need to be changed every time you modify the number and quality of the incoming arrays.

This solution has a big O on *n*. If the three arrays have 1000 rows, then `array_column()` will iterate 1000x with no iterated function calls.  Then the `foreach()` will iterate 2000x and call `array_merge()` each time (potentially merging the current row with an empty array).  So there will only be millions of iterations if you have millions of rows of data.

The above can be translated to functional iteration too. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/c9Mbv))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            array_merge($array2, $array3),
            function($result, $row) {
                $result[$row['id_produto']] = array_merge($result[$row['id_produto']] ?? [], $row);
                return $result;
            },
            array_column($array1, null, 'id_produto')
        )
    )
);
```

Also, you can use a native recursive function as well.  I don't know how it compares in terms of performance, but the readability is arguably better than the other options.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nfGUD))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_replace_recursive(
            array_column($array1, null, 'id_produto'),
            array_column($array2, null, 'id_produto'),
            array_column($array3, null, 'id_produto')
        )
    )
);
```