# How to make array first value as key for the second value as value in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays structured like below:

```
array(2) {
  ["uid"]=>
  string(2) "39"
  ["name"]=>
  string(18) "Manoj Kumar Sharma"
}
array(2) {
  ["uid"]=>
  string(2) "47"
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "S kK Mishra"
}
```

I want these array should be like this below:

```
array(4) {
      [39]=>
      string(18) "Manoj Kumar Sharma"
      [47]=>
      string(11) "S kK Mishra"
    }
```

How can i achieve this ? Please help me.

Comment: just use a `foreach`, then assign it in another array using `uid` as the key and `name` as the value, you can just try

Comment: Above one is single multidimensional array or two different single- dimensional array?

Comment: @A-2-A, there is no difference, imho...

Comment: difference is there. you didn't get me.

Comment: @A-2-A, if it isn't `multidimensional array` but you need it to be that way - you can just make it `multidimensional array`. So, where is the difference, exactly?

Comment: Related: [How to convert array first value as key and second value as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559841/how-to-convert-array-first-value-as-key-and-second-value-as-value/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated**

You can try this with [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) -

```
$new = array_column($arr, 'name', 'uid');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/520115)

Note: `array_column()` not available for **PHP < 5.5**

If you are using lower versions of **PHP** the use a loop.

```
$new = array();
foreach($your_array as $array) {
    $new[$array['uid']] = $array['name'];
}
```

Comment: `array_column` accepts a third parameter, which would make this even easier. Read the documentation you link to again yourself.

Comment: @deceze Thanks. Never went through that. :)

Comment: thats working fine as i required. but i have one issue with my current query which i am executing.  $results = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT u.uid as uid, u.name as name FROM users u WHERE u.uid IN (SELECT p.endpoints_entity_id as uid FROM 

field_data_endpoints p JOIN relation r ON r.rid = p.entity_id WHERE p.bundle = 'subuser' AND p.deleted = 0 AND p.delta = 0 AND r.uid = 

$user->uid)")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); This query creating duplicate array. How can i resolved this issue.

Comment: You can apply `array_unique` to the array. Can you add the actual array you are getting.

Comment: **Googlers**: heads up, if you simply need to re-index the array, set `column_key` (2nd argument) to `null`, and `index_key` to the value name that needs to become the key