# How to convert array first value as key and second value as value

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I am working on some array operations.

I need to convert first value of array as key and second value of array as value.

I have one variable **$testArray** which stores array like below.

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Color
            [1] => White on Red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Depicted Text
            [1] => EMPTY
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Depth [Nom]
            [1] => 0.004 in
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Language
            [1] => English
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Length [Nom]
            [1] => 10 in
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Material
            [1] => Adhesive Vinyl
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mounting
            [1] => Surface
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Width [Nom]
            [1] => 14 in
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Wt.
            [1] => 0.056 lb
        )

)
```

**Expected output :**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Color] => White on Red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Depicted Text] => EMPTY
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Depth [Nom]] => 0.004 in
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Language] => English
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Length [Nom]] => 10 in
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Material] => Adhesive Vinyl
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Mounting] => Surface
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Width [Nom]] => 14 in
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Wt.] => 0.056 lb
        )

)
```

**I have already tried with array function array_keys and array_values but it won't working**

Comment: want to convert it into key value form like `[Length [Nom]] =>10 in`

Comment: Related, and with a (better?) answer: [How to make array first value as key for the second value as value in php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451153/how-to-make-array-first-value-as-key-for-the-second-value-as-value-in-php-array)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple solution using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function:

```
$result = array_map(function($v){
    return [$v[0] => $v[1]];
}, $testArray);
```

Comment: Looks good, but only works if you don't need the first-level array keys to be modified. I needed a value to become an actual array key and this didn't help

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that structure will always be the same, you could do this:

```
$output = array();
foreach($testArray as $v){
    $output[] = array($v[0] => $v[1]);
}
```

See it in action [here](https://3v4l.org/bfoh1).