# php pass by reference in array_map function

Tags: php, array-map

I am trying to use array_map function to parse query string and get a key=>value pair:

```
function parse_query_string($string)
{
    $result = [];
    $arry = explode('&',$string);

    $get_qry_str_array = function($str, &$result) 
    {
        $a = explode('=',$str);
        $result[$a[0]] = $a[1];
    };

    array_map($get_qry_str_array,$arry, $result);
    return $result;
}
```

if i use this function as below i was expecting it would return an associative array with each query string parameter and value as key=>value pair because i am passing the **$result** variable as reference.

```
$qry_str_array = parse_query_string('edit=1&delete=2');

print_r($qry_str_array);
```

That is i am expecting an array like:

```
[
    'edit' => 1,
    'delete' => 2,

]
```

but i am getting an empty array.

Am i using this in a wrong way? I am new to php world, relatively.

Comment: Just use `http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php` to parser such strings

Comment: I will look into that. But i am actually being curious here. Why is it not working - @splash58?

Comment: array_map set just one argumet for each array so your function does not receive result . do it `$get_qry_str_array = function($str) use(&$result)`

Comment: `array array_map ( callable $callback , array $array1 [, array $... ] )` - the function definition says that additional arguments can be passed to be used as the arguments of the callback function. It's from the documentation and there are examples of that too... - @splash58

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559841/how-to-convert-array-first-value-as-key-and-second-value-as-value for an example of doing this. You don't need to use a reference to build up the outer array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `array_map` function isn't changing the `$result` array as you'd expect. The callback function `$get_qry_str_array` should be set up to take an element from the input array `$arry` and update the $result array.

```
function parse_query_string($string)
{
    $result = [];
    $arry = explode('&', $string);

    $get_qry_str_array = function ($str) use (&$result) {
        $a = explode('=', $str);
        $result[$a[0]] = $a[1];
    };

    array_map($get_qry_str_array, $arry);
    return $result;
}

$qry_str_array = parse_query_string('edit=1&delete=2');

print_r($qry_str_array);
```

Removed the reference `&$result` from the array_map function because the callback function now uses the use statement to explicitly import the $result variable.
Modified the callback function to take only one parameter `$str` since array_map passes each element of the array as a separate argument to the callback function

```
expected result

Array
(
    [edit] => 1
    [delete] => 2
)
```

Please try code in PHP Editor - https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_intro