# Extract and convert multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array from an api call.
I want to format it before to play with values in my view.

This is my array

```php
$myArray = array(
            array(
                array(
                    "Name" => "firstname",
                    "Value" => "Mat"
                ),
                array(
                    "Name" => "name",
                    "Value" => "Doe"
                ),
                array(
                    "Name" => "city",
                    "Value" => "Dallas"
                ),
                array(
                    "Name" => "date_of_birth",
                    "Value" => "1975-05-22T22:00:00Z"
                ),

            )
        );
```

I need to format it like this

```php
$myNewArray =
            array(
                "firstname" => "Mat",
                "name" => "Doe",
                "city" => "Dallas",
                "date_of_birth" => "1975-05-22T22:00:00Z"
            );
```

I'm trying with many foreach but no success. I'm looking about functions array on https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php but I don't know which of them is for my case.

It will be nice to guide me. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert array first value as key and second value as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559841/how-to-convert-array-first-value-as-key-and-second-value-as-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the data of value and then combine it with keys

```
$myArray = array_shift($myArray);
$result = array_combine(array_column($myArray, 'Value'), array_column($myArray, 'Name'));
print_r($result);
```

Other alternative by using array_column,

```
$myArray = array_shift($myArray);
$result = array_column($myArray, 'Value','Name');
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [firstname] => Mat
    [name] => Doe
    [city] => Dallas
    [date_of_birth] => 1975-05-22T22:00:00Z
)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e67e3a29119594e216f5f25cf59b91d825a79ee).

[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_column`

```
$res = array_column($myArray[0], 'Value','Name');
print_r($res);
```

OR

Using `array_walk`

```
$res = [];
array_walk($myArray[0], function($v, $k) use(&$res){
    $res[$v['Name']] = $v['Value'];
});
echo '<pre>';
```

Result

```
Array
(
 [firstname] => Mat
 [name] => Doe
 [city] => Dallas
 [date_of_birth] => 1975-05-22T22:00:00Z
)
```