# In associative array, how to make the first element of each array element a key

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array(
 [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-10-05
            [1] => 24,57
            [2] => 24,65
            [3] => 23,86
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-10-04
            [1] => 24,38
            [2] => 24,675
            [3]=> 24,24
        )
   )
```

I want to convert this into

```
Array(
 [2017-10-05] => Array
        (

            [0] => 24,57
            [1] => 24,65
            [2] => 23,86
        )

    [2017-10-04] => Array
        ( 
            [0] => 24,38
            [1] => 24,675
            [2] => 24,24
        )
```

This question similar to [How to make array first value as key for the second value as value in php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451153/how-to-make-array-first-value-as-key-for-the-second-value-as-value-in-php-array).   But i can't use `array_column` in my case,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code with array_slice:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($array as $a) {
    $newArray[$a[0]] = array_slice($a, 1); 
}
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/TQUIW39810)

Comment: Good Solution, I am trying to do this with array_walk, But i think this is better and simpler , Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that. Welcome.

Comment: Btw another version of this would be  `$newArray = [];
foreach($array as $a) {
  $first_ele = array_shift($a);
  $newArray[$first_ele] = $a;}`  
    `

Comment: Yeah, I would even shorten it by one line `foreach($array as $a) { $newArray[array_shift($a)] = $a;}`

Comment: And if golfing, do away with the curlies.